# Display wpf datagrid row column data(controls) into canvas

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am using WPF Datagrid in which rows will be addded dynamically.
I can create wpf controls such as label, textbox, button, etc. into the selected datagrid cells dynamically.

I need to show the datagrid cell content controls into canvas. In other words, controls in rows and columns need to be displayed in tabular format on canvas.

Does anyone know how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but you can use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` to specify that an item should be drawn as a `Canvas`

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColumnHeader">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Label ... />
                <TextBox ... />
                <Button ... />
            </Canvas>
         </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If you're looking to position items on an unrelated `Canvas` outside the `DataGrid`, that's a different story since there is a hierarchy to `DataGrid` UI components, and you can't easily place an item outside that hierarchy.

If that is the case, I'd suggest you switch to using an `ItemsControl`

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want the grid controls to be placed on canvas when i click on navigate button which will show canvas and there it needs to be displayed. I am using datagrid template column itself.But I just want to know how to bind the elements or drop the grid controls on canvas.